# Centering the map in print composer around a feature (QGIS)

Tags: qgis, print-composer

I have to frequently generate the same 15 maps for work, same data each time (mostly) but at different locations for each project. Is there way that the print composer could actually auto-center itself around a polygon that I created?
I know I can just click "set map extent to match main canvas extent" it does what I want, but I'm hoping to use a plugin that auto-print all my 15 different maps in one go.

Currently by default the composer uses the last extents used, and I have to individually open each layout to re-set the extents to the current extent. Is there any way I can set it so that it loads centered around the data I'm using?

Comment: I suggest you have a look at the atlas feature.

Answer (score 8):

This is what the Atlas feature in QGIS is designed to do.

In the Layout view click the button at the top on the far right called Atlas Settings:[image]

Set the Coverage layer to the polygon layer that you want to iterate through, configure the rest of the options there as you see fit, sorting, filtering, etc if needed.

Then go to the Map item in the Layout table of contents and go to Item Properties. Scroll down and check Controlled By Atlas. Under here you can decide if you want to use a fixed scale if you want the map to zoom to a centain percentage around each feature.

At the top again, click the Preview Atlas button: [image] and start flicking through pages.

That's a very quick description, if you need more then I recommened going through the QGIS tutorial page on the Atlas.